# Mostrar datos guardados en una base de datos en una tabla de html

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Buenas tardes tengo una pequeña consulta, tengo una tabla en html y quiero mostrar en la tabla unos datos que tengo en una base de datos de pl/sql de oracle me guaria saber que debería poner en la etiquetas html para que me deje visualizar los datos, la tabla que tengo hasta el momento es así:

`````
<table id="custom_tool_ele" class="table table-striped table-bordered display dataTable" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="custom_tool_ele_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custom_tool_ele" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 165px;">
                                <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">TURNO</font>
                                </font>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custom_tool_ele" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 253px;">
                                <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">FECHA INICIAL</font>
                                </font>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custom_tool_ele" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 121px;">
                                <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">FECHA FINAL</font>
                                </font>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custom_tool_ele" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 63px;">
                                <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">MODIFICAR</font>
                                </font>
                            </th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class=""><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">jackson bradshaw</font></font></td>
                            <td><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Director</font></font></td>
                            <td><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Nueva York</font></font></td>
                            <td><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">sesenta y cinco</font></font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="even">
                            <td class=""><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">sábalo</font></font></td>
                            <td><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Director Regional</font></font></td>
                            <td><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Edimburgo</font></font></td>
                            <td><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">51</font></font></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
````
`````

Comment: Duda: como sacas los datos de la base de datos, usas AJAX?

Comment: Tienes algun API?

Comment: si, los datos los saco con AJAX

Comment: Básicamente debes iterar con un ciclo el `array` de datos que obtienes con `ajax` en el `tbody` de la tabla. Por cada registro de la BD, maquetas un `<tr></tr>`  y dentro de cada `<tr></tr>` maquetas un `<td></td>` con la información de cada campo.